# How to print a string and all the n lines of that string bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, grep

Hi All can you please help me I am trying to get the following output so basically I have 2 input files and we need only the common :names from both the input files along with there the lines below them the .name/of/file lines.

Till now I have tried:

```
 awk '/:name1/{flag=1} flag;/ /{flag=0}' /path/of/input/file1
```

Output:

```
:name1
    ./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 1 ]
```

But its only printing the first line.

**Input file1:**

```
:name1
./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 1 ]
./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 1 ]

:name2
./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 1 ]

:name3
./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 24 ]
./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 24 ]

:name4
./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 3 ]
./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 3 ]
./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 3 ]
./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 3 ]

:name5
./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 6 ]
./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 6 ]
```

**Input file2:**

```
:name1
:name3
:name4
```

**Required Outputfile**:

```
:name1
    ./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 1 ]
    ./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 1 ]
:name3
    ./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 24 ]
    ./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 24 ]
:name4
    ./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 3 ]
    ./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 3 ]
    ./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 3 ]
    ./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 3 ]
```

Comment: `/ /` will match on any space anywhere in the line hence the reason `flag=0` fires after the first line (with spaces) is printed

Comment: donee thnaks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One `awk` approach:

```
awk '
FNR==NR { a[$1]; next }
NF<=1   { flag=0   }           # clear flag if zero or one non-white-space fields is present in the current line
$1 in a { flag=1   }           # set flag if 1st field is an index in the a[] array
flag                           # if flag == 1 then print current line to stdout
' file2 file1
```

This generates:

```
:name1
./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 1 ]
./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 1 ]
:name3
./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 24 ]
./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 24 ]
:name4
./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 3 ]
./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 3 ]
./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 3 ]
./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 3 ]
```

Comment: Thankyou so much its working for me but how can we only get the first occurrence of the :names

Comment: @aastha I don't understand what you mean by `first occurrence`; I don't see any of the names showing up more than once in `file1` so ... not sure what is meant by `first occurrence`

Comment: let me edit the input file1 I forgot to mention that 

Comment: sorry I didn't knew that btw thanks

Answer (score 3):

Output can also be made indented:

```
awk 'NR == FNR { for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) a[$i] = 1; next }
    a[$1] { $1 = $1; print }' RS= FS='\n' OFS='\n\t' file{2,1}
```